# MySQL PHP id from on table to another

Tags: php, mysql

I have constructed a array that gets the information from checkboxes. This is working fine, however i require a second input where the id of a second table is placed next to the array data. For example, when a user inputs data to my php form, it generates a id on one table, whereas my checkboxes are saved to a second. I want when the user selects the checkbox, the id is placed here. The problem i have is that i dont know just where to put this data.

```
$insertSQL2 = "INSERT INTO Project_course (Proj_id Cour_id) SELECT Course_id FROM courses WHERE 
Code IN (";
foreach ($_POST['CheckboxGroup1'] as $Q){
$Q = mysql_real_escape_string($Q);
$insertSQL2.= "'$Q', ";
 } 
 $insertSQL2 = rtrim($insertSQL2, ", ");
$insertSQL2 .= ")";
```

Proj_id is where the id need to go, while Cour_id is where it checkboxes are saved. Aswell as this, it needs to happen simultaneously as the relationship in the mysql table means that one column cannot be blank.

I know this was long winded, so any help will be gratefully accepted

Comment: could you specify where the "Proj_ID" would come from? Your code only shows how you are constructing your query to insert a relationship between that data and the checkboxes you talk about, but not where that data comes from? is it another INSERT query? data on the form?

Comment: Exactly. Please, provide us with table structure (of course only essential fields) and form structure (the same).

Comment: The form that this is on allow a user to input data, which is then saved to the table projects. The checkbox data is saved to the table project_course where it gets the id that is linked to the code of that checkbox, saved as cour_id. I want the proj_id to link to the project table, so when the cour_id column is filed with its data, the proj_id is given the id of the last entry in the project table. For example, when the user selects all 4 checkboxes, the cour_id is given 1 2 3 4 in seperate rows and i want these to be given the id from the project table in the proj_id column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the form first saves project data, and then - some course data connected with this project.

BTW - first thing I suggest is to leave pure mysql_* functions in favour of PDO. But this is offtopic.

Anyway - first you probably run something like

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO project (col1, col2) VALUES (blah1, blah2)";
mysql_query($sql)
```

Then you can check the new project ID simply by invoking

```
$projectID =  mysql_insert_id();
```

And then something like

```
foreach ($_POST['CheckboxGroup1'] as $key => $val)
{
    $_POST['CheckboxGroup1'][$key] =  mysql_real_escape_string($val);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO project_course(project_id, course_id) SELECT ".$projectID.", course_id FROM courses WHERE code IN (".implode(", ", $_POST['CheckboxGroup1']).")";
```

UPDATE - if you already have a project in your project table, you may get project ID in several manners. For example by using `SELECT project_id FROM project ORDER BY project_id DESC LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Thanks alot, Sorry for the long time without responding. This worked a treat, just needed to amend some of the code.